# Calendar reminders with Office 365 Rest API

Tags: office365

I am working on an application that will interact with a users Calendar using the Office 365 REST API.
There does not seem to be any way to configure the reminder settings for an event in the calendar using the REST API.

Is this something that is missing from the API or am I missing something?

Thanks
Gavin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you're not missing anything. The API doesn't currently support it. We're constantly adding to the API though, so hopefully that makes it in. Keep an eye on our [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/) or follow me on Twitter (@JasonJohMSFT) to get announcements related to the APIs.